# How to check and set if current time is out of specific range [Javascript/jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I would like to submit some forms with the time which the time must be in specific range time. If it is out of specific range time, it will be generated in new time which is in specific range time.

**My specific range time is 08:30-17:30 on weekday.**

If current time is not on weekday, sets the day to Monday at 08:30.

Ex. if current time is Saturday 12:00 ,sets it as Monday 08:30

If current time is less than 08:30, sets the time to 08:30 on that day.

Ex. if current time is Tuesday 01:00 ,sets it as Tuesday 08:30

If current time is more than 17:30, sets the time to 08:30 on tomorrow.

Ex. if current time is Tuesday 20:00 ,sets it as Wednesday 08:30

If current time is on Friday and the time more than 17:30, sets the time to 08:30 on Monday.

Ex. if current time is Friday 20:00 ,sets it as Monday 08:30

Could someone please help? Thank you.

```
function CreatedDateFunction() {
    var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat'];
    var now     = new Date(); 
    var day     = days[now.getDay()]
    var date    = now.getDate();
    var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
    var year    = now.getFullYear();
    var hour    = now.getHours();
    var minute  = now.getMinutes();
    var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
    if(month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0'+month;
    }
    if(day.toString().length == 1) {
        var date = '0'+date;
    }   
    if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0'+hour;
    }
    if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0'+minute;
    }
    if(second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0'+second;
    }   
    var datetime = day+' '+date+'/'+month+'/'+year+' '+hour+':'+minute;
    var nowDay = day;
    var nowDate = date+'/'+month+'/'+year;
    var nowTime = hour+'.'+minute;
    document.getElementById('idCreatedate').value= datetime;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){CreatedDateFunction()},500);
    sessionStorage.setItem('aDate',date);
    sessionStorage.setItem('aMonth',month);
    sessionStorage.setItem('aYear',year);
    sessionStorage.setItem('nowDay',nowDay);
    sessionStorage.setItem('nowDate',nowDate);
    sessionStorage.setItem('nowTime',nowTime);
}

function checkFunction() {
    var date = sessionStorage.getItem('aDate');    
    var month = sessionStorage.getItem('aMonth');
    var year = sessionStorage.getItem('aYear');
    var nowDay1 = sessionStorage.getItem('nowDay');    
    var nowDate1 = sessionStorage.getItem('nowDate');
    var nowTime1 = sessionStorage.getItem('nowTime');
    alert("Day: " + nowDay1);
    alert("Date: " + nowDate1);
    alert("Time: " + nowTime1);
    if(nowDay1!='Sat'&&nowDay1!='Sun'){
        if(nowTime1>08.30 && nowTime1<17.30){
            console.log("Yes, time is in range");
            //Next, plus priority date(High=2days,Medium=3days,Low=4days) and check again to be sure that it is not on Sat, Sun
        }else{
            console.log("no, time is out of range");
            //check <8.30 or >17.30 to do next 
            //if(nowTime1<08.30){
                //set to that day at 08.30
            //}else if(nowTime1>17.30){
                //set day+1 and date+1 at 08.30 
            //}
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Have to set to Mon 08:30");
        //nowDay1 = 'Mon';
        //nowTime1 = '08.30'
    }
}
```

Comment: please show what you tried.

Comment: Can you post code in this post rather than only in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will do:

```
function checkRange(d) {
   var hours = d.getHours();
   var mins  = d.getMinutes();
   var day   = d.getDay();
   var dayOfWeek = 1;

   if(day >= 1 && day <= 5){
     if(hours < 8 || (hours === 8 && mins <= 30)){
       d.setHours(8, 30, 00);
       return d;
     }
     else if(hours > 17 || (hours === 17 && mins > 30)){
       (day === 5) ? d.setDate(d.getDate() + (dayOfWeek + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7) : d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
       d.setHours(8, 30, 00);
       return d;
     }
   }
   else{
     d.setDate(d.getDate() + (dayOfWeek + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
     d.setHours(8, 30, 00);
     return d;
   }
   return 'Time is in the range';
}
console.log(checkRange(new Date('09/12/2015 20:30:00')));
```

Comment: Could you explain me why we have to check the hours like
if(hours < 8 || (hours === 8 && mins < 30)) ,not check like 
if(hours === 8 && mins < 30)

Comment: Well, first question would be, does this work for you?

Comment: It's not completely work. For example, console.log(checkRange(new Date('09/25/2015 20:30:00'))); It will return 'Sat Sep 26 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)'.

Comment: Updated the condition, you can try now.

Comment: It still doesn't complete.  For example, console.log(checkRange(new Date('09/25/2015 10:30:00'))); It will return 'Mon Sep 28 2015 08:30:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)'.

Comment: Hold on I am fixing it.

Comment: This one is not clear. Are you saying 09/25/2015 10:30:00 should return 09/25/2015 10:30:00?

Comment: Can you please try it now!

Comment: This code is work. Thank you so much for your help. If possible, could you explain me a bit why we have to check hour like that.

Comment: Nothing special about it. It's just I prefer that way. :)